# Prevent Communicator from opening a new Outlook window for conversation searches?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, office-communicator-2007

I'm running Office Communicator 2007 R2, and Outlook 2007 SP2, on Windows XP SP3.

Whenever I right-click a contact in Communicator and select "Find Previous Conversations", it opens a new window in Outlook to do the search.  Aside from just cluttering up my taskbar and work space, I imagine this also takes a bit more time than it would to just run the search in the existing Outlook window.

Is there any way to change this behavior?